# Azure CDN Standard Akamai CORS failed

Tags: azure-cdn, akamai

i am using hls/dash for video streaming using azure akamai cdn but every time its getting failed due to `CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

i config cors into my storage account but i am unable to stream video

```
<Cors>      
      <CorsRule>  
            <AllowedOrigins>*</AllowedOrigins>  
            <AllowedMethods>GET,HEAD,OPTIONS</AllowedMethods>  
            <AllowedHeaders>*</AllowedHeaders>  
            <ExposedHeaders>server,range</ExposedHeaders>  
            <MaxAgeInSeconds>3000</MaxAgeInSeconds>  
    </CorsRule>  
<Cors>
```

is their any other way to config cors in cdn

Comment: I see that the error states "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". Did you modify the response Header to use this header?

Comment: can u take a look at this [link](https://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test?format=dash&manifest=https%3A%2F%2Fstream.azureedge.net%2F10386%2Fdash%2F_tS4mdmuHpl8Ahakzb4Vm.mpd)

Comment: if i access the file directly from browser i getting this response headers                   access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: server,range
content-length: 1057487
content-md5: kDo3OQdvmMUXMGfR1QIKDw==
content-type: video/mp4
date: Fri, 24 May 2019 08:09:38 GMT
etag: 0x8D6DF9A1AC232B1
last-modified: Thu, 23 May 2019 16:17:08 GMT
server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
status: 200
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-request-id: db25abc2-a01e-003f-7808-120b40000000
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19

Answer (score 0):

Akamai CDN doesn’t have CORS settings and it will pass all headers from the Origin. So, as long as the origin returns CORS headers and CDN Edge Server has not cached the old resource, it will return CORS headers.

Comment: look at this 2 links 1 from cdn and one from direct storage                                           1. [cdn link](https://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test?format=dash&manifest=https%3A%2F%2Fstream.azureedge.net%2F%2F550750241860046129207%2F10437%2Fdash%2FAZzmL0-fHegixWo_58XQZ.mpd)                                                                                                2. [direct link](https://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test?format=dash&manifest=https%3A%2F%2Fstreambucket.blob.core.windows.net%2Fvideos%2F550750241860046129207%2F10437%2Fdash%2FAZzmL0-fHegixWo_58XQZ.mpd)

Comment: Is the CORS in the Storage Account is set as *

Comment: Also, try to purge, when you make changes to the config to make the changes to reflect

Comment: Yes it's set to *

Comment: I have taken Fiddler capture for both the Link and I do see one difference: 
Working :GET /videos/550750241860046129207/10437/dash/media-video-avc1.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Non-Working :OPTIONS //550750241860046129207/10437/dash/media-video-avc1.mp4 HTTP/1.1

In the non-working , the method is OPTIONS and ?video is missing . 
Also I see there are no cache.

Comment: i added origin path to 'videos' container when i create this endpoint thats why i dont added it into it.